# Access SQL, select multiple rows duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates

I need to select all my duplicates in a table, however the duplication must be spread through two rows. I tried some stuff which lead me to this code:

```
SELECT builder_2, sequence, clientname_2, clientPcode_2, status
  FROM tblClient
 WHERE clientname_2 IN (SELECT clientname_2
                          FROM tblClient
                         GROUP BY clientPcode_2, clientname_2
                        HAVING (COUNT(clientPcode_2) > 1) AND (COUNT(clientname_2) > 1)
                        )
   AND clientPcode_2 IN (SELECT clientPcode_2
                           FROM tblClient
                          GROUP BY clientPcode_2, clientname_2
                         HAVING (COUNT(clientPcode_2) > 1) AND (COUNT(clientname_2) > 1)
                        )
 ORDER BY clientPcode_2, clientname_2
```

However, this code is not working for obvious reasons, it selects any duplicates in both fields, so if a client name appear on two lines, he is considered "duplicate" even if the postal code doesn't match.

I tried to do a single sub-select where I would add the primary keys (Number and Sequence), however the result was not what I wanted, seemed to be because of the group by. I can't explain it, but my test data were missing from the sample so I rejected the solution.

Comment: So you are looking for rows where both the client name and postal codes are the same, right?

Comment: Yes, but as I said in the proposed answer, I also need to be able to set some filters. For example, all the clientname + postalcode with "REJECTED" status must be ignored. Not only the line with the REJECTED status, but also the duplicate it is associated with. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this would do what you are looking for. It is essentially just moving your `WHERE IN` clauses to a `JOIN` which is more flexible.

```
SELECT  T1.builder_2, T1.sequence, T1.clientname_2, T1.clientPcode_2, T1.status
FROM    tblClient T1
        INNER JOIN 
        (   SELECT  clientname_2, clientPcode_2
            FROM    tblClient
            GROUP BY clientname_2, clientPcode_2
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        ) AS T2
            ON T1.clientname_2 = T2.clientname_2
            AND T1.clientPcode_2 = T2.clientPcode_2
```

**EDIT**

I am not sure exactly how you want to filter this so will add an example to show 3 ways in which you could filter the data.

Sample Data (Only relevant columns)

```
clientname_2    |   clientPcode_2   |   Status
----------------+-------------------+--------------------
ClientA         |   M1 2AA          |   Accepted
ClientA         |   M1 2AA          |   Pending
ClientA         |   M1 2AA          |   Rejected
ClientB         |   M1 2AA          |   Accepted
ClientB         |   M1 2AA          |   Rejected
ClientC         |   M1 2AA          |   Accepted
ClientC         |   M1 2AA          |   Pending



SELECT  T1.builder_2, T1.sequence, T1.clientname_2, T1.clientPcode_2, T1.status
FROM    tblClient T1
        INNER JOIN 
        (   SELECT  clientname_2, clientPcode_2
            FROM    tblClient
            WHERE   Status NOT LIKE '%Rejected%'        -- FILTER A
            GROUP BY clientname_2, clientPcode_2
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
            AND     SUM(IIF(Status LIKE '%Rejected%', 1, 0)) = 0    -- FILTER C
        ) AS T2
            ON T1.clientname_2 = T2.clientname_2
            AND T1.clientPcode_2 = T2.clientPcode_2
WHERE   Status NOT LIKE '%Rejected%'                        -- FILTER B
```

**FILTER A ONLY**

This will limit it to only client/postcode combinations that have 2 or more rows where the status is not Rejected. Rows with a status of rejected will still be returns.

```
clientname_2    |   clientPcode_2   |   Status
----------------+-------------------+--------------------
ClientA         |   M1 2AA          |   Accepted
ClientA         |   M1 2AA          |   Pending
ClientA         |   M1 2AA          |   Rejected
ClientC         |   M1 2AA          |   Accepted
ClientC         |   M1 2AA          |   Pending
```

**FILTER B ONLY**

This will find all client/postcode combinations that are duplicated, and return only the rows where the status is not rejected:

```
clientname_2    |   clientPcode_2   |   Status
----------------+-------------------+--------------------
ClientA         |   M1 2AA          |   Accepted
ClientA         |   M1 2AA          |   Pending
ClientB         |   M1 2AA          |   Accepted
ClientC         |   M1 2AA          |   Accepted
ClientC         |   M1 2AA          |   Pending
```

**FILTER A AND FILTER B**

This will just limit the result set of just filter a to remove the row where the status is rejected

```
clientname_2    |   clientPcode_2   |   Status
----------------+-------------------+--------------------
ClientA         |   M1 2AA          |   Accepted
ClientA         |   M1 2AA          |   Pending
ClientC         |   M1 2AA          |   Accepted
ClientC         |   M1 2AA          |   Pending
```

**FILTER C**

This will only return client/postcode combinations where no row exists for with the same combination with a status of Rejected:

```
clientname_2    |   clientPcode_2   |   Status
----------------+-------------------+--------------------
ClientC         |   M1 2AA          |   Accepted
ClientC         |   M1 2AA          |   Pending
```

Comment: This seems to work, however I can't add filtering. For example, if the status is "REJECTED" I would need to ignore the duplicates. I could get it to remove the REJECTED line, but not the initial line too. I tried to put it in the INNER JOIN, but the the test data went missing again. Any idea how I could achieve this ?

Comment: @Estarius, where did you try to add the filter? In the subquery or the outer query?

Comment: Please clarify, what do you mean 'test data went missing again'? What exactly happens if you change the inner query conditional to `HAVING COUNT(*)>1 AND status NOT LIKE "REJECTED"`?

Comment: it tells me status is not part of the aggregate function, so I add it in my GROUP BY. Then, I take a look at the result and search for a case which I know is a reported duplicate, but it doesn't show up anywhere in the results.

Comment: Well I'm not sure about the nature of the data, but adding an additional GROUP BY (which is required) could have undesirable effects. I would suggest pre-filtering the sub results by making another subquery. I will make an edit and see if GarethD will accept.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14467/discussion-between-estarius-and-nicholas)